# Can we shift all children of a canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, children

What I am doing is creating a line graph of the data which comes from Serial Port.

My drawing part of the code is;

```
private void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (X1 < Canvas.ActualWidth)
        {
            Line myLine = new Line();
            X1 = X1 + 1;
            X2 = X2 + 1;


            myLine.X1 = X1;
            myLine.Y1 = Y1;
            myLine.X2 = X2;
            myLine.Y2 = Y2; //Y2 comes from serial port
            myLine.Stroke = Brushes.Aqua;
            myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
            Canvas.Children.Add(myLine);
            Y1 = Y2;




        }
        else
        {
            Canvas.Children.Clear();
            X1 = 0;
            X2 = 1;
        }
    }
```

As you see from the code, when the line reaches to the end of the canvas it clears all the children (lines) and starts it from left beginning of the canvas all over again (kind of refreshing)

Now I want it to start shifting the all children ( as user sees the Line Graph) to the left. So we can get a continious dynamic plot.

Is there a way to shift all children of the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply change the `X1` and `X2` values of the already existing lines:

```
foreach (var line in currentCanvas.Children.OfType<Line>())
{
    line.X1 -= 10;
    line.X2 -= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this example and work it into your solution.

Remember to check that the left coordinate is greater than zero before subtracting from it....

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Background="BlueViolet" Margin="58,69,0,0">
            <Button Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="100" Width="40" Height="30">Test 1</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Top="120" Canvas.Left="80" Width="40" Height="30">Test 2</Button>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.Cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

        ShiftCanvasChildrenLeft(Canvas1, 10);
            //add new lines code here...
}

private void ShiftCanvasChildrenLeft(Canvas currentCanvas,Double shiftLeftBy )
{
        foreach (UIElement child in currentCanvas.Children)
        {
                //get the current left location
                Double currentLeftLocation = Canvas.GetLeft(child);
                //subtract 10 from the current location
                Double newLeftLocation = currentLeftLocation - shiftLeftBy;
                //move the child left
                Canvas.SetLeft(child, newLeftLocation);
        }

}
```

Comment: Oh. foreeach changed everything. Thank you. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: There appears only one problem. How to refresh (redraw) the canvas? This probably is working but I can't see because canvas.Refresh() doesn't exist in WPF.

Comment: No need to redraw the canvas, all of the childen will move